# How to update the maven dependcencies in pom at runtime

Tags: java, maven-3

I have a dependency included in my pom

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
        <version>1.84.3</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

At the moment i'm manually checking if there is any new release for this jar and i update the version in pom xml.

But i would like to know if there is a way to automate during runtime?

Comment: why would you want to do it on a running application. It defeats the whole purpose of what Maven is for, not to mention if you update the program while its running, some of the updates might break your program. It is always best to do it manually and test the updates to make sure your program won't break in production.

Comment: Do you really mean while program is running to update dependency?

Comment: Yes while the application is running. It is needed because this test fails because of the incorrect test jar version then i have to manually look for the latest version and update the version in pom. So i was looking for an alternative to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven `versions` tool to [update dependencies versions](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-latest-version)

> Updating every non-SNAPSHOT dependency to its latest release works in the same way, simply changing the goal to `versions:use-latest-releases`:
>
> ```
> mvn versions:use-latest-releases
> ```

Comment: But that will not update the dependencies on the classpath of a running application (and handle all the classloading issues which would be related to this).

Comment: @FrVaBe I thought OP didn't really mean on running per se, I thought on "working application"